# How to change axis scale on imagesc in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-scaling, axis-labels

I have a 15x15 image of a grid of numbers which I have shown using imagesc. However, the axis goes up to 450 in both directions, when I only want it to go up to 15. I tried:

```
axis/30;
```

But that doesn't do anything? All I want to do is divide the x and y axes by 30!

Comment: I dont see problem, bacause code: img =rand(15);
imagesc(img); is working well (bring colorful matrix 15x15)... Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, I presume, that although your image shows 15 numbers along in each axes, the total size of your image in pixels is 450 x 450 - and this is what `imagesc` is using.

So, what you really have is an image with 15 x 15 blocks of 30 x 30 pixels.  You can set the axes ticks and labels manually using `XTick` and `XTickLabel`:

```
atick = 15:30:415; %assuming you want the ticks in the centre of each block
set(gca,'XTick',atick);
set(gca,'XTickLabel', 1:15);
set(gca,'YTick',atick);
set(gca,'YTickLabel', 1:15);
```

Comment: Cool thank you. Do I do this before calling imagesc?

Comment: call `imagesc` first.